# UILabel truncating after scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a scroll view with images and multi-line text.
After load the screen, I do this to recalculate the content size:

```
    CGRect contentRect = CGRectZero;
    for (UIView *view in self.scrollview.subviews) {
        contentRect = CGRectUnion(contentRect, view.frame);
    }
    self.scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollview.contentSize.width, contentRect.size.height + 10);
```

It works fine, however, when I touch the screen to scroll the content, the UILabel with multi-line text is truncated to 1 line.
I did a video showing it happening:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qzvu9m_XQJk&feature=youtu.be
If I remove the above code, the text doesn't truncate. But the screen won't scroll with a big text. Any idea about how to fix that?

Comment: Are you using auto layout to set up the label and the scrollview?

Comment: Have you using auto layout or not?

Comment: cgrectunion? what is that for?

Comment: The scrollview uses auto layout like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/iwd959bb9nh0pf7/Screen%20Shot%202015-09-16%20at%2010.56.23%20AM.png?dl=0 and for label I didn't set any constraint because the height constraint was not showing the label correctly with more lines.

Comment: did you check what value "contentRect" retuns?

Comment: did you added view in scroll view then add your label, or directly added your label in scroll view?

Comment: Set a height constraint and connect it to an IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint.  Then calculate the size of your UILabel based on the text (I can post some code to show you how if you choose this path) then change the value of the UILabel height constraint to the height of the text.  Should force the label to be the correct height and not resize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers, but after many tries I gave up trying to fix this problem on scroll view.
I remade the screen using table view. My screen has a header, image with a button, message and comments. Then I used 3 custom cells, one for header, one for image, one for message and one for each comment. It works very well, without problem.

Most likely this is not the correct way to do that, in my point of view this screen should use scroll view, but I couldn't find a way to make it work with multi-line labels. Also because the comments are added in runtime and it was breaking everything. When comments were added to screen, it was truncating the message label.